# Convert Postman code to regular C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postman

[image: postman screen shot]

```
var client = new RestClient("https://seller.digikala.com/Account/Login");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "0e4d8dba-29da-0b26-1b43-1bf974e9b5de");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I can send request successfully and login to site in postman, but I can't do it in VS. This is my code in VS:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://seller.digikala.com/Account/Login");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("IsPersistent", true, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("Password", "myPass", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("UserName", "myUsername", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("returnUrl", "/Account/Login", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

but I get "unauthorized" message (401) in VS

Comment: Any errors? Informational messages back?

Comment: @andrewb  i couldn't do it in vs. and get unauthorized message(401)

Comment: Run a fiddler trace for both VS and Postman and check the payload difference.

Comment: Just a thought, try adding a User-Agent header in the C# code.

Answer (score 6):

you can use PostMan Auto C# Code generator

[image: PostMan Auto C# Code generator]

Comment: To my understanding you need to use https://restsharp.dev/ to [generate code from postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-code-generators/tree/develop/codegens/csharp-restsharp). The OP mentions "regular c#" which could mean that he wants to avoid 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that you're adding things that should be part of the body as parameters (based on the screenshot from PostMan showing these items as part of the body). This is untested but may work for you.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://seller.digikala.com/Account/Login");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddBody(new
{
    IsPersistant = true,
    Password = "myPass",
    UserName = "myUsername",
    returnUrl = "/Account/Login"
});
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I get this error when request.AddBody hit "Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C."

Comment: Where does that happen exactly? Sounds like you're passing invalid characters.

Comment: when addBody hit. but add `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;` before addBody fix this error. although i get 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do a `GET` of the page first, then when making then `POST` reflect back all cookies received during the GET (if that RestClient of yours doesn't do that automatically).

Login pages typically add a cookie during GET and expect that cookie during POST to prevent XSRF (this involves including that same token as a form's hidden field, although the XSRF token is apparently not present in your Postman payload). It also wouldn't surprise me that some cookie-based sessionID filter is blocking you even before your request hits the login controller/middleware. In any case, doing the GET first and then reflecting the cookies in POST should work.

Comment: but i trace the login with postman interceptor there isn't any antiforgerytoken field in form.

Comment: That may be so, I even said that your Postman screenshot doesn't show one, but other cookies may still be important.

Answer (score 0):

Other responses are good too but if you’re looking for a tool that does a little more than postman’s snippet generator, I created a tool that will generate an entire ApiClient project for you, generating classes for query parameters, requests, responses, form data and more.

It’s pretty extensive in terms of features and should work right when you download the project with the exception of a few complicated authentication types.

It’s open source, free and runs in the browser too (keeps your data safe). [https://postman2csharp.com/Convert](https://postman2csharp.com/convert)